# Contact Form is not displaying in php script

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I have created a code snippet (given below) in php script for **CONTACT Form**. The Form is not displaying itself when there is no error shown in the Console. One issue is raised saying that **"Audit usage of navigator.userAgent,navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform"**.
I am using Windows 10 and sublime text editor. React JS is also installed in my computer.
Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['send'])) { 


$to_mail = $_POST['tomail'] ;
$subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
$body = $_POST['message'] ; 
$from_mail = $_POST['frommail'];
$header = "From: $from_mail" ;

    mail($to_mail, $subject, $body, $header) ;


    if(mail($to_mail, $subject, $body, $header)){

            echo "We have sent a mail to your mail id. Kindly check and confirm." ;

        }else{

            echo "No mail could be sent to you." ;

        }

     } 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <?php include 'header.php' ; ?>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="container-contact">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-12">
                     <form class="cform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER('PHP_SELF')) ;?>" method = "POST">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>To</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="tomail"> <br><br>

                            <label>Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject"> <br><br>

                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" `enter code here`cols="40" rows="15"></textarea> <br><br>

                            <label>From</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="frommail"> <br><br>

                            <button><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"></button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the source of your resulting page, and I'll bet you see an error like... "Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in (your file name)".

Answer (score 1):

@Subhajit

line number 37 : you have use the small bracket , but $_SERVER is the array and you have to use the big bracket [ and ]

```
<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER('PHP_SELF')) ;?>
```

- solution e.g echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ;

there was the error "fatal error Function name must be a string" that due to you have used the server variable properties with small brackets.

Comment: @Guarang I was trying to hint OP to look at the line for the issue  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to Mr. Gaurang. My problem of displaying the CONTACT FORM has been solved. I am feeling extremely ashamed for making such silly mistake that was supposed to get noticed at my end only. However I am feeling grateful to you. But one thing I must mention is the issue of  "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent,navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform" is still alive. Should I ignore it or what to do now.